# Can you use two HTML templates such as Handlebars and Jinja

Tags: ember.js, flask, jinja2, handlebars.js

I'm trying to write an app in javascript with the ember.js library which relies heavily on the Handlebars templating system. However, I'm using FLASK which also uses the jinja templating system.

Is it possible to use both template renderers at the same time? Or do I need to use one over another. Anyone with experience using both flask and ember.js know which one would potentially be easier to replace with the other?(Maybe handlebars is much easier to replace Jinja with or vice versa).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that these two template engines are in different places. Jinja2 will run on the server side, Handlebars will run on the client side. You could potentially use both without interference if you needed to.

But with that said, there is really no need to use server-side templates if you have a rich client framework like ember.js. In your situation the Flask server will likely have routes that serve data via ajax requests back to the ember.js client, so the client is really the best place for template rendering to happen.

Comment: I am using node.js for the server and am using a mix of jade with handlebars templates.  Jade still gives me and most importantly my designer and another non-technical person a very easy file to edit. (They could still edit raw html, but jade is just really clean)  When I have to put in handlebars actions and link to's, I simply use raw html within the template.  Works out nicely for us.

Comment: The best web-apps (most performant) render a full html page on first load and then use client-side rendering to update it. Relying on the client to fully bootstrap the initial page increases the page load significantly (subsequent ajax calls have to be made).

Comment: Should be noted — Handlebars can be rendered on either side, but Jinja is rare on the client side.

Answer (score 10):

You can mark sections of code as `{% raw %}` to tell jinja2 to ignore it. Wrap your handlebars.js template in raw tags like so:

```
{% raw %}
<script id="foo-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>{{foo}} - {{bar}}</p>
</script>
{% endraw %}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Miguel said, you don't really need Jinja2 if your using ember.js, I figured out if you don't want to render those templates, simply return flask.send_file('your html file here') instead returning flask.render_template('your html file here'). See the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=send_file#flask.send_file) for more details.

Comment: it's even better to have the html files handled as static files. During development Flask can serve them directly from the "static" folder. During production your web server should serve these files bypassing Flask. You should only use Flask for the ajax requests. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

While I fundamentally agree with both @Miguel and @Ali, several companies I have worked with mix the RESTful model for APIs with server-generated HTML. [**NOTE:** This shouldn't be the case when using Ember, but I'm working with Flask / Jinja2 and Backbone in my current client's code base.]

I actually found a solution using [Pybars](https://github.com/wbond/pybars), based on some reading from [Khan Academy's style guide](https://sites.google.com/a/khanacademy.org/forge/for-developers/all-about-rendering-web-pages/client-side-templating):

```
@app.template_filter("handlebars")
def handlebars_filter(context, filepath):
    source = open( filepath, "r").read().decode('utf-8')
    template = pybars.Compiler().compile( source )

    return Markup( u"".join( template( context )))
```